# Why this gives an error when I run in snowflake?

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
add_months(CURRENT_DATE() - 1,'MONTH')
```

throws an error

> Invalid argument types for function '>=': (ROW(TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), VARCHAR(5)), DATE)

Comment: You will need to provide the full query for anybody to have a chance to help you.

Comment: The month parameter should not be in single quotes. That parameter takes a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax would be like below as per documentation:

```
select current_date(), add_months(current_date(), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm) and [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/add_months.html), the syntax is:

> ```
> ADD_MONTHS( <date_or_timestamp_expr> , <num_months_expr> )
> ```

So you would want:

```sql
add_months(CURRENT_DATE, -1)
```

*(Note: `CURRENT_DATE()` can also be used in Snowflake but not in Oracle.)*

Comment: I used add_months(trunc(CURRENT_DATE(),'mm'), -1)      this resolved my issue. Thanks